True comparison of country sizes when plotting GeoDataFrame of countries with matplotlib
When plotting subplots of different countries, the axis ratios are not the same among subplots, showing the countries with incorrect sizes.
Kenya is much bigger than the others but shows as big as the others.
GeoJson files can be accessed here: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/posNqG9l#link
strCountries = ["ghana", "kenya", "zimbabwe"]
admin1Countries = []
for country in strCountries:
    regions = gpd.read_file(f"../data/admin1{country}.geojson")
    admin1Countries.append(regions)

# real size in one plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for regions in admin1Countries:
    regions.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()

# wrong size when plotting next to each other
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))
for i, regions in enumerate(admin1Countries):
    regions.plot(ax=ax[i])
    ax[i].set_title(strCountries[i].capitalize())
    ax[i].set_axis_off()
plt.show()



I tried changing the CRS to those corresponding to the regions of the countries. Nothing changed. I also tried with axs[i].set_aspect('equal')

I can not get the file, it says: "The transfer you requested has been deleted."

thanks, @Taras. I don't know what happened. I uploaded it to another service and edited the link.

It is not a CRS problem but  a Matplotlib problem. By default, each axe is scaled individually depending on the size of the figure to be represented (see Creating multiple subplots using plt.subplots)

Duplicate not reported in True comparison of country sizes when plotting GeoDataFrame of countries with matplotlib
